# Where can I find the version for ubuntu that can run on 2gb ram

Tags: 14.04

I have a Windows 10 64 bit with 3gb ram laptop and I am trying to find the lightest version that can run on my pc without destroying or crashing it but where can I find that version?

Comment: You will probably want to look at [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) or [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/download). Both are pretty decent on system requirements 

Comment: I used laptops & devices with as little as 1GB of RAM for testing *flavors* up to and including 19.04 (ie. 2019-April release), and they were still used for the last 18.04.5 *re-spin* release (2020-October).  The 2GB is only part of the picture; the lightest out-of-the-box *flavor* is Lubuntu in my opinion (be it *legacy* or *modern*), but if you're using GTK3+ apps it may not be the best choice (Qt5 apps for sure). User preferences also play a role, as it's somewhat like your *favorite ice-cream*...  Either the way 14.04 you tagged is EOL or ESM & off-topic.